# Перехват исключений в службе Windows

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service

Есть служба Windows, которая является хостом для WCF-службы. При инициализации службы Windows подписываюсь на событие

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException;

private void CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    Logger.Error("UNHANDLED", e.ExceptionObject);
}
```

Периодически служба падает и я могу наблюдать только запись с кодом 7034 в журнале системы о том, что служба неожиданно прервана.

Как узнать что приводит к крашам службы? Весь код реализован через блоки try/catch, с логгированием, но в логах нет ни одного исключения.

UPD

Вывод команды sc query после краша:

```
SERVICE_NAME: LWPServiceHost
TYPE: 10 WIN32_OWN_PROCESS
STATE: 1 STOPPED
WIN32_EXIT_CODE: 1067 (0x42b)
SERVICE_EXIT_CODE: 0 (0x0)
CHECKPOINT: 0x0
WAIT_HINT: 0x0
```

Comment: Я думаю, это никак не связано с исключениями. Подобное событие легко воспроизвести например, если прибить процесс службы диспетчером задач. Покажите вывод команды `sc query (имя службы)` после падения.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, добавил вывод команды в шапку.

Comment: [Handle Windows Service Errors](https://www.devopsonwindows.com/handle-windows-service-errors/) - в этой статье все объяснено.

Comment: Код возврата 0x42b характерен именно для принудительного завершения процесса функцией TerminateProcess (как кнопка "Снять задачу" в диспетчере задач), а не для необработанного исключения. Так что я тут скорее подозреваю проблему в самой ОС или каком-то стороннем софте (вроде антивируса), а не в вашем сервисе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В итоге выяснилось, что виной падений является попытка одновременного обращения к COM-компоненту в нескольких потоках (в следствии ошибки в конфигурации WCF-службы). При этом не вырабатывалось исключение, а служба просто завершала свою работу.

При возникновении подобных проблем стоит обратить внимание на системный журнал "Приложение". В нем я нашел события с кодом 1000 по моей службе, где была информация о сбойном модуле.

@Alexander Petrov в комментариях к посту предоставил ссылку на отличную статью, в которой подробно описана обработка исключений в службах Windows.

Спасибо @Alexander Petrov и @MSDN.WhiteKnight за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Создать отдельный общий класс ошибок типа SamplError

```
//Чисто для примера взял из головы
     class SamplError
        {
            [DataMember]
            public string Reason = "";
            public SamplError()
            {
            }
            public SamplError(string error)
            {
                Reason = error;
            }
        }
//Добавим проверку на то, что имя уже есть
[DataContract]
    class SamplNameExistException : SemplError { }

//Пример вызова
    try{}
    catch (Exception e)
                {
                    throw new FaultException<SamplNameExistException >(new SamplNameExistException(), e.Message);
                }
```

вот неплохая статья про Ваш случай
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.unhandledexception?view=netframework-4.8